# Qt QDebug não funciona (não exibe as mensagens)

Tags: c++, qt, debug

Eu possuo o sistema operacional Fedora 23 e utilizo Qt para desenvolver interfaces gráficas (GUI), entretanto meu debugger não funciona:

Estou tentando **imprimir mensagens no console utilizando qDebug()**, mas **nada é exibido**. Já tentei de tudo e nada resolve!

**O que devo fazer para concertar o qDebug()?**

Answer (score 1):

Muito simples! **As mensagens do qDebug() foram desabilitadas por padrão no Fedora**. Para habilitar as mesmas, você deve adicionar a seguinte linha de código ao seu programa:

```
QLoggingCategory::defaultCategory()->setEnabled(QtDebugMsg, true);
```

Lembrando que o seu código também deve incluir os headerer **QDebug** e **QLoggingCategory**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLoggingCategory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLoggingCategory::defaultCategory()->setEnabled(QtDebugMsg, true);

    qDebug() << "FINALMENTE FUNCIONOU!";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Mas quer exibir no console do QTIDE ou no terminal? Porque se for terminal eu acho que não deve-se usar `qDebug()`.

Comment: Funciona em ambos!